# Multiple order values for find_with_reputation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The following function sorts the businesses (relation) by votes descending (using the active record reputation system [link to gem](https://github.com/twitter/activerecord-reputation-system)).

```
@businesses = Business.find_with_reputation(:votes, :all, order: "votes desc")
```

How would I add a secondary order value so that it sorts by votes but if votes are equal it sorts by created_at (oldest at the top)?

Is it simply:

```
@businesses = Business.find_with_reputation(:votes, :all, order: "votes desc, created_at desc")
```

Comment: although i have no clue what "find_with_reputation" does, but this looks correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that your proposed answer is going to result in a SQL error because 'created_at' probably occurs in both the reputation table and the Business table.  To get around that, I'd suggest being specific on created_at.

```
Business.find_with_reputation(:votes, :all, order: "votes desc, businesses.created_at desc")
```

However, I'd suggest instead that you use the id column.  DBs will be faster with INTs and the sort sequence should be the same.

```
Business.find_with_reputation(:votes, :all, order: "votes desc, businesses.id desc")
```